# Create a list with all the words (including hyphenated words) that have more than 3 vowels

Tags: python

I have this string

```
tw =('BenSasse, well I did teach her the bend-and-snap https://twitter.com/bethanyshondark/status/903301101855928322 QT @bethanyshondark Is Reese channeling @BenSasse https://acculturated.com/reese-witherspoons-daughter-something-many-celebrity-children-lack-work-ethic/ , Twitter for Android')
```

I need to create a list with all the words that have more than 3 vowels. Please help!

Comment: Show your own effort and code to solve the problem (as properly formatted text in the question)

Comment: please show some attempt (here is a hint to get you started `for word in tw.split():`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `re.findall` with the following regex:

```
import re
re.findall(r'(?:[a-z-]*[aeiou]){3,}[a-z-]*', tw, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
```

This returns:

```
['BenSasse', 'bend-and-snap', 'bethanyshondark', 'bethanyshondark', 'Reese', 'channeling', 'BenSasse', 'acculturated', 'reese-witherspoons-daughter-something-many-celebrity-children-lack-work-ethic', 'Android']
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you start with creating a list of all vowels:

`vowels = ['a','e','i','o','u']`

Well, a list of letters (Char) is really the same as a string, so I would just do the following:

`vowels = "aeiou"`

After that I would attempt to split your string into words. Let's try `tw.split()` like Joran Beasley suggested. It returns:

`['BenSasse,', 'well', 'I', 'did', 'teach', 'her', 'the', 'bend-and-snap', 'https://twitter.com/bethanyshondark/status/903301101855928322', 'QT', '@bethanyshondark', 'Is', 'Reese', 'channeling', '@BenSasse', 'https://acculturated.com/reese-witherspoons-daughter-something-many-celebrity-children-lack-work-ethic/', ',', 'Twitter', 'for', 'Android']`

Are you fine with this being your "words"? Notice that each link is a "word". I'm going to assume that this is fine.

Ok, so if we access each word with a for-loop, we can then access each letter with an inner for-loop. But before we start, we need to keep track of all the accepted words with 3 or more vowels, so make a new list: `final_list = list()`. Now:

```
for word in tw.split():
    counter=0 #  Let's keep track of how many vowels we have in a word
    for letter in word:
        if letter in vowels:
            counter = counter+1
    if counter >= 3:
        final_list.append(word) #  Add the word if 3 or more vowels.
```

If you now do a print: `print(final_list)` you should get:

`['BenSasse,', 'bend-and-snap', 'https://twitter.com/bethanyshondark/status/903301101855928322', '@bethanyshondark', 'Reese', 'channeling', '@BenSasse', 'https://acculturated.com/reese-witherspoons-daughter-something-many-celebrity-children-lack-work-ethic/']`

Comment: You beat me to it!!  I was just doing something similar!